# Как сделать перезагрузку компонента во Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Необходимо перерисовать компонент после события отправки формы.
Как вызвать перерисовку?

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal h">
            <div class="close_area" @click="modal_close"></div>
            <div class="formContainer">
                <!-- Add New Post -->
                <form action="" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
                    <button type="button" class="close" @click="modal_close">+</button>
                    <label>
                        Название записи
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Введите название записи"
                            v-model="headline"
                            :class="{invalid: ($v.headline.$dirty && !$v.headline.required)}"
                        >
                        <small
                            v-if="$v.headline.$dirty && !$v.headline.required"
                        >
                            headline не должен быть пустым
                        </small>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Текст записи
                        <textarea
                            cols="10"
                            rows="10"
                            placeholder="Введите тест записи"
                            v-model="posttext"
                            :class="{invalid: ($v.posttext.$dirty && !$v.posttext.required)}"
                        >
                        </textarea>
                        <small
                            v-if="$v.posttext.$dirty && !$v.posttext.required"
                        >
                            posttext не должен быть пустым
                        </small>
                    </label>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Добавить запись</button>
                </form>
                <!-- / Add New Post -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- / Modal -->
```

Вот метод

```
 async handleSubmit() {
                    if (this.$v.$invalid) {
                        this.$v.$touch();
                        return
                    }

                    try {
                        await this.$store.dispatch('createRecord', {
                            headline: this.headline,
                            posttext: this.posttext,
                            date: new Date().toJSON()
                        });
                        console.log('Записано!');
                        this.$v.$reset();
                        this.headline = '';
                        this.posttext = '';
                        this.modal_close();

                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log('ERROR')
                    }
                    console.log('Отправка')
                },
```

Comment: `this.$forceUpdate()` не помогает?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не сработало.

Comment: 1) Зачем это надо? Даже в доке написано, что если вы пытаетесь вручную обновить компонент, то 99%, что вы делаете что-то не правильно 2) А как Вы это определили, что компонент не обновился?

Comment: У меня есть форма которая доабвляет посты в приложение(Назовем это новости) мне нужно сделать так чтобы при добавлении довости она отображалась на текущей странице, по этому нужно перерисовать компонент откуда они подтягиваются

Comment: Не нужно перерисовывать. Добавьте новость в массив, в котором у Вас содержаться другие новости - и Vue сам все перерисует

Comment: Если бы это происходило я бы не пришел на Стековерфлов)

Comment: У меня после отправки формы новость улетает на сервер, так вот когда она улетела, мне нужно перерисовать дочерний компонент

Comment: Зачем что-то перерисовывать? У вас новости в vuex хранятся? После отправки формы вызовите action.. Вам 100% не нужно его перерисовывать, просто вызывайте метод загрузки после отправки формы, либо добавляйте элемент в массив в самом вью, не посылая дополнительные запросы на сервер. Вам нужно решить проблему или же написать велосипед из костылей?

Comment: Важно реализовать правильно, наверное я действительно както не правильно решил найти выход из ситуации, нужен не костыль нужно чтобы этот пост отображалься когда его добавил пользователь

Answer (score 2):

Пример кода добавления новости:

```js
const NewsItem = Vue.component('news-item', {
  template: `<li> {{news}}</li>`,
  props: ['news']
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { NewsItem },
  data() {
    return {
      newsList: ['Новость №1', 'Новость №2'],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendNews(event, news = `Новость №${this.newsList.length +1}`) {
      // ... здесь код отправляющий новсть на сервер
      this.newsList.push(news)
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
  <news-item v-for="news in newsList" :news="news" :key="news" />
  </ul>
  <button @click="sendNews($event)">Отправить новость</button>
</div>
```

Пример кода с принудительным обновлением

```js
const NewsItem = Vue.component('news-item', {
  template: `<li> {{news}}</li>`,
  props: ['news'],
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { NewsItem },
  data() {
    return {
      newsList: ['Новость №1', 'Новость №2'],
      isShow: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    reloadComponentForce() {
      this.$forceUpdate();
    },
    reloadManual() {
      this.isShow = false;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.isShow = true;
      });
    },
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('updated');
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
  <news-item v-for="news in newsList" :news="news" :key="news" v-if="isShow" />
  </ul>
  <button @click="reloadComponentForce">Перегрузить с $forceUpdated</button>
  <button @click="reloadManual">Перегрузить вручную</button>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня немного другая структура, я использую Vue CLI
И у меня на Странице вывод новостей подружаеться из компонента

Comment: Сначала идет форма а потом
<PostsEdit/>
В компоненте Пост едит уже и выводятся посты и его и нужно перерисовать

Comment: добавил примеры. Но 99% - вы что-то делает не правильно

Comment: Возможно просто я не совсем понимаю что нужно сделать, мне нужно чтобы пост отобразился на странице когда его добавили, я думаю значит нужно дернуть компонент который их отображает

Comment: Не правильно думаете. Добавьте рабочий пример, тогда Вам смогут помочь

Comment: Вот ссылка на фидл https://jsfiddle.net/078sjpcq/

Comment: там ошибка "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: Я просто структуру документов показал